# Must the following correlation matrix have a nonzero eigenvalue $\le 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, correlation

For $k=1,\dots,K$ with $K\ge 2$, let $\boldsymbol{v}_k$ be a $r_k$-dimensional random vector whose mean is zero and covariance matrix is the identity matrix ${\bf I}_{r_k\times r_k}$. 
Also $span(\boldsymbol{v}_k^\top)\ne span(\boldsymbol{v}_{k'}^\top)$ for any $k\ne k'$. Here $span(\boldsymbol{v}_k^\top)$ means the space spanned by entries of $\boldsymbol{v}_k$.

$\boldsymbol{v}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{v}_K$ can follow different distributions with unequal $r_k$,
and can be correlated with each other.

Must the correlation/covariance matrix of the concatenated vector $(\boldsymbol{v}_1^\top,\dots,\boldsymbol{v}_K^\top)^\top$ have a "nonzero" eigenvalue $\le1$.

Note that in this case, the correlation and covariance matrix of $(\boldsymbol{v}_1^\top,\dots,\boldsymbol{v}_K^\top)^\top$ are the same, and can be low-rank.

I know this is true for $K=2$, but what if $K>2$?

Comment: This question is not very clear.  Is it about a sample correlation matrix or about a population correlation matrix?  How can rank deficiency hold if the covariance matrix is the identity matrix?  And so on.  Is this a sanitized version of a more comprehensible problem?  "Harry" seems to understand what is really being asked; I confess I do not.

Comment: @kimchilover I am asking for the population correlation matrix.

Comment: If it is the identity matrix, where does your "low rank" comment come from?

Comment: The identity matrix is set for the covariance matrix of a single vector $\boldsymbol{v}_k$ . The covariance matrix of the concatenated vector $(\boldsymbol{v}_1^\top,\dots,\boldsymbol{v}_K^\top)^\top$ can be low rank, for example, if the space spanned by entries of $\boldsymbol{v}_1$ intersects the space spanned by entries of $\boldsymbol{v}_2$.

Comment: So the big correlation matrix you are really interested in has small $r_k\times r_k$ identity matrix blocks on the diagonal, but might have more or less arbitrary junk on the off diagonal blocks?  So it might, for instance, be $\begin{pmatrix} I&Q\\ Q' & I\end{pmatrix}$ where $I$ is a $4\times4$ identity matrix and $Q$ is a $4\times4$ othogonal matrix? In which case the eigenvalues are four copies each of 2 and 0.

Comment: @kimchilover I revised the question again by "Also $span(\boldsymbol{v}_k^\top)\ne span(\boldsymbol{v}_{k'}^\top)$ for any $k\ne k'$. Here $span(\boldsymbol{v}_k^\top)$ means the space spanned by entries of $\boldsymbol{v}_k$."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64121/discussion-between-kimchi-lover-and-john).

Comment: @user1551, correlation matrix is semi-positive definite. So the eigenvalues are nonnegative.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I really need some coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  And even if $K=2$, the correlation matrix might be $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$, which has eigenvalues 2 and 0.

Comment: In this case, correlation and covariance matrices are the same, and they can be low-rank. So your answer is not correct.

Comment: $v_1,\dots,v_K$ can be from different distributions.

Comment: I am asking for the correlation matrix of the concatenated  vector $(v_1^\top,\dots,v_K^\top)^\top$. It can be low-rank. So your answer is not for my question at all.

Comment: @kimchilover, your answer indeed is not correct, because the matrix can be low rank. So if all eigenvalues are greater than 1, their sum can be $\sum r_k$ here. I am interested in this question also. And wait for the answer.

Comment: @kimchilover I am sorry, I forget to mention the eigenvalues of interest are nonzero. So my question here is:  Must the correlation matrix has a nonzero eigenvalue $\le 1$?

Comment: @kimchilover, thank you for letting me realize the mistake.

Comment: I have revised my answer to fit the new question, and deleted my previous comments.

Comment: @kimchilover  I revised the question again by "Also $\boldsymbol{v}_k\ne \boldsymbol{v}_{k'}$ almost surely for $k\ne k'$" to remove the trivial case.